# How to split big compressed text file to small text files

Tags: python, file, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp

I want to convert this corpus [hu.txt.xz](https://data.statmt.org/cc-100/hu.txt.xz)  **15GB**  which becomes around **60GB** after unpacking to small versions of text files, each file with less than **1GB** or **100000** lines

```
The expected output: 
     | siplit_1.txt
     | siplit_2.txt
     | siplit_3.txt
        .....
     | siplit_n.txt
```

I have this script on a local machine but doesn't work it just loads without process because bigdata as I think :

```
import fun
import sys
import os
import shutil
#  //-----------------------
# Retrieve and return output file max lines from input
def how_many_lines_per_file():
    try:
        return int(input("Max lines per output file: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Please use a valid number.")
        sys.exit(1)

#  //-----------------------
# Retrieve input filename and return file pointer
def file_dir():
    try:
        filename = input("Input filename: ")
        return open(filename, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error: File not found.")
        sys.exit(1)


#  //-----------------------
# Create output file
def create_output_file_dir(num, filename):
    return open(f"./data/output_{filename}/split_{num}.txt", "a")


#  //-----------------------
# Create output directory
def create_output_directory(filename):
    output_path = f"./data/output_{filename}"
    try:
        if os.path.exists(output_path):  # Remove directory if exists
            shutil.rmtree(output_path)
        os.mkdir(output_path)
    except OSError:
        print("Error: Failed to create output directory.")
        sys.exit(1)

def ch_dir():
    # Print the current working directory
    print("Current working directory: {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
    # Change the current working directory
    os.chdir('./data')
    # Print the current working directory
    print("Current working directory: {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
#  //-----------------------
def split_file():
    try:
        line_count  = 0 
        split_count = 1 

        max_lines = how_many_lines_per_file()

        # ch_dir()
        input_file  = fun.file_dir()
        input_lines = input_file.readlines()

        create_output_directory(input_file.name)
        output_file = create_output_file_dir(split_count, input_file.name)

        for line in input_lines:

            output_file.write(line)
            line_count += 1

            # Create new output file if current output file's line count is greater than max line count
            if line_count > max_lines:
                split_count += 1
                line_count = 0

                output_file.close()

                # Prevent creation of an empty file after splitting is finished
                if not len(input_lines) == max_lines:
                    output_file = create_output_file_dir(split_count, input_file.name)

    # Handle errors
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unknown error occurred: {e}")

    # Success message
    else:
        print(f"Successfully split {input_file.name} into {split_count} output files!")


#  //-----------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    split_file()
```

Is there any python script  or deep learning tool to split them for using the to next task

Comment: What does "just loads without process" mean?  Please be more specific about the behavior you're getting vs what you expect.

Comment: I don't what the problem is for example if I use a smaller text file with 400MB it does splitting,  But when try to split (hu.txt.xz) like halt no errors appear (as I think memory can not load all data  at the same time  )
So I am looking for a way to modify my script with a chunk (read segment by segment)

Comment: If I'm not wrong you're trying to allocate the file in memory which is not possible because It is too big. The technical solution is to read the file as a stream of data and read chunks then process them. *instead of trying to read all at once*.

Comment: Thanks @Mike93041 you are right , But how can I do that ?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter since you need to change the logic already, but I think the line `if not len(input_lines) == max_lines:` is incorrect.  It appears that neither `input_lines` or `max_lines` will change inside the loop, so either this test will always succeed or it will always fail.  I assume that you expect this line to avoid creating an extra file at the end of the processing.  It won't do that.

Comment: Yes, what @Mike93041 says makes sense. I think if instead of iterating over the result of calling readlines(), you iterate over the file handle (`with open('xxx') as f: for line in f:`), you will have better results.  This will read and process one line at a time, never having more than one line in memory at the same time.

Comment: @دايخفيزمنبايخ I'll post how you do it in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to allocate a big file into memory which is not possible.

Instead of reading all the content at once just read line by line and process it.

I've fixed the bug seen by @CryptoFool

```
import fun
import sys
import os
import shutil
#  //-----------------------
# Retrieve and return output file max lines from input
def how_many_lines_per_file():
    try:
        return int(input("Max lines per output file: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: Please use a valid number.")
        sys.exit(1)

#  //-----------------------
# Retrieve input filename and return file pointer
def file_dir():
    try:
        filename = input("Input filename: ")
        return open(filename, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error: File not found.")
        sys.exit(1)


#  //-----------------------
# Create output file
def create_output_file_dir(num, filename):
    return open(f"./data/output_{filename}/split_{num}.txt", "a")


#  //-----------------------
# Create output directory
def create_output_directory(filename):
    output_path = f"./data/output_{filename}"
    try:
        if os.path.exists(output_path):  # Remove directory if exists
            shutil.rmtree(output_path)
        os.mkdir(output_path)
    except OSError:
        print("Error: Failed to create output directory.")
        sys.exit(1)

def ch_dir():
    # Print the current working directory
    print("Current working directory: {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
    # Change the current working directory
    os.chdir('./data')
    # Print the current working directory
    print("Current working directory: {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
#  //-----------------------
def split_file():
    try:
        line_count  = 0 
        split_count = 1 

        max_lines = how_many_lines_per_file()

        # ch_dir()
        input_file  = fun.file_dir()

        create_output_directory(input_file.name)
        output_file = None # No output file is created at first, we need to check if there's any line if it enters the for

        for line in input_file:
            # Open a new output file if we don't have one open
            if not output_file:
                output_file = create_output_file_dir(split_count, input_file.name)

            output_file.write(line)
            line_count += 1

            # Close the current output file if the line count has reached its max
            if line_count > max_lines:
                split_count += 1
                line_count = 0

                output_file.close()
                output_file = None

    # Handle errors
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unknown error occurred: {e}")

    # Success message
    else:
        print(f"Successfully split {input_file.name} into {split_count} output files!")


#  //-----------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    split_file()
```

Comment: A minor detail...your check for if a new output file should be opened or not is not right.  `line_count` will always be zero, so the test will always be `true`. I don't think there's any way to do the right thing there.  You can't know if there are more lines to be written until you try to get another line.  I updated my answer with how I would address this issue.  Feel free to copy any part of my answer to yours.

Answer (score 2):

By calling `readlines()` on the input file handle, you are reading (or trying to) the whole file into memory at the same time.  You can do this instead to process the file one line at a time, never having more than a single line in memory:

```
    input_file  = fun.file_dir()

    ...

    for line in input_file:
        ...
```

Another issue to be aware of is that this line:

```
if not len(input_lines) == max_lines:
    output_file = create_output_file_dir(split_count, input_file.name)
```

is likely not doing what you think it is. Neither `input_lines` or `max_lines` will ever change inside the loop, so this will either always create a new file or never will.  Unless you happen to process a file with exactly `max_lines` lines in it, this will always be `true`.  This is not a big deal, but I think as your code is now you're going to end up with an extra empty file.  You need to change the logic anyway, so you'll have to rethink how to make this work.

UPDATE:

Here's how I would modify the logic to do the right thing regarding opening each of the output files:

```
input_file = fun.file_dir()

# output_file = create_output_file_dir(split_count, input_file.name)
output_file = None

...

for line in input_file:

    # Open a new output file if we don't have one open
    if not output_file:
        output_file = create_output_file_dir(split_count, input_file.name)

    output_file.write(line)
    line_count += 1

    # Close the current output file if the line count has reached its max
    if line_count > max_lines:
        split_count += 1
        line_count = 0

        output_file.close()
        output_file = None
```

The key idea here is that you can't know if you need a new output file until you have tried to read the next line after closing the current output file. This logic only opens an output file when it has a line to write out and there is no open output file.